# Parsing timestamp in nginx logs

Tags: regex, bash, nginx

I need help as I am new to log parsing. I'm trying to extract all log lines that have a 200 status, with a timestamp of 15 hours before 15:35. I am not able to figure out the regex to be used.

Here is a sample of the log:

> 198.104.78.160    [26/Dec/2016:15:24:12 -0500]    200 190.50.175.65:8080  200 testtest.com    GET /api/bid_request?feed=1&auth=qwerty&ip=85.194.119.3&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+Win64%3B+x64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F48.0.2564.97+Safari%2F537.36&lang=tr-TR%2Ctr%3Bq%3D0.8%2Cen-US%3Bq%3D0.6%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.4&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fserve.pop.net%2Fs
>   HTTP/1.0  -   -   -   174.194.36.141  -   0.109-0.009 US  */*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do that :

```
awk -v status_code=200 -v ts_at_hour=15 -v ts_before_hour=15 -v ts_before_min=35 '

    {
        match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s+\[[0-9]{2}\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\/[0-9]{4}:([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\s+[+-][0-9]{4}\]\s+([0-9]{3})/, items)

        if (items[1] == ts_at_hour && 
            items[1] <= ts_before_hour && 
            items[2] < ts_before_min &&
            items[4] == status_code){
          print $0
        }
    }
' data.txt
```

Set some variables to store your requirements `status_code`, `ts_at_hour`, `ts_before_hour` and `ts_before_min` (you can define environment vars to them)

The regex is a `match` that focus on 4 groups : hour, minutes, seconds defined by `([0-9]{2})` and status_code at the end `([0-9]{3})`

To decompose the regex, you have :

- the IP address `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` followed by space `\s+` (or more)
- the date part which includes hour,minutes and seconds `\[[0-9]{2}\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\/[0-9]{4}:([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\s+[+-][0-9]{4}\]` (notice the 3 groups between `()`)
- the status code with `([0-9]{3})`